# $n$ black squares on a grid become disappear in $n$ moves.

Tags: proof-writing, induction, puzzle

Found this fun puzzle:

On an infinite sheet of white graph paper (a paper with a square grid), $n$ squares are colored black. At moments $t = 1, 2, . . .$, squares are recolored according to the following rule: each square gets the color occurring at least twice in the triple formed by this square, its top neighbor, and its right neighbor.

Prove that after the moment $t = n$, all squares are white!

**My solution:**

I'm not sure how to make it rigorous though if anyone can help me out and it's not quite correct.

Complete induction on $n$: for all $k < n$ squares, it will be converted after $k$ steps. Let $R$ be smallest rectangle containing all black squares. Let $r$ be the bottom-row and $c$ be left-most column. By IH, $R - r$ takes $<n$ steps and $R - c$ takes $<n$ steps. Then the sum of steps is $<2n$. The last square is in bottom left at $r \cap c$, which will go with $1$ step. In total, we have $2n + 1$ steps, but I'm doubling counting because $R - c \cap R - r$. So, i'm not sure how to proceed, since we're trying to prove it will take at most $n$ steps.

I'd appreciate if someone could help with this!

Comment: Interesting puzzle! My first thought was to show that the number of black squares decreases by $1$ each time, but this is not the case:$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\bullet&\bullet\\\hline&\bullet\\\hline\end{array}
\quad\longrightarrow \quad
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\bullet&\\\hline\bullet&\bullet\\\hline\end{array}
\quad\longrightarrow \quad
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline&\\\hline\bullet&\\\hline\end{array}
\quad\longrightarrow \quad
$$

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was included in *An Invitation to Discrete Mathematics*, and that they give a hint which is basically a full solution. They have a similar idea to you, considering the bottom-most row and left-most column. However, you need to do a better estimate; since $R-r$ and $R-c$ are gone in at most $n-1$ steps, it follows that $(R-r)\cup (R-c)$ is also gone in at most $n-1$ steps. You do not need to add the numbers of steps, since the processes are happening at the same time. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why is it the case the $(R-r) \cup (R-c)$ takes at most $n-1$ steps? In the "maximum" case, wouldn't one square be in $r$ and one be in $c$, meaning it would take at most $n-2$ steps? But if i'm wrong and it is at most $n-1$ steps, I'm still not sure how to proceed. Especially in terms of step count, and providing a good reasoning for the bottom-left square being left over.

Comment: @HughFranco, the point is, everything above the bottommost row is gone in $n-1$ steps, and everything to the right of the leftmost column is gone in the *same* $n-1$ steps, so the only thing possibly left after $n-1$ steps is the *single* square constituting the *intersection* of the bottommost row and the leftmost column.

Comment: Is there some way to make that rigorous? @BarryCipra

Comment: I posted a solution to a duplicate of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4119344/11206).